# Download the uploaded image through input file in react

Tags: reactjs, node.js, input, download, multer

what I want is when the user selects a profile pic the pic gets stored in the client-side folder does anyone have an idea?

I tried Multer but it stores the images in the server-side folder in my case the server and client are hosted on different sites

and thank you all for helping